# How many names appear on San Francisco's Wall of the Vanished?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, after Scott Lang returns from the Quantum Realm, he visits the [Wall of the Vanished](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Wall_of_the_Vanished), anxiously trying to established whether his daughter Cassie was spared -- only to discover that his own name appears on the list.

[image: Overview of the Wall of the Vanished with the Golden Gate bridge in the background]

I think it's reasonable to assume this memorial is for the city or region around San Francisco, as a national memorial would need to have 150 million entries and likely wouldn't be located in San Francisco.  And similarly a global memorial falls to the same logic in the even more extreme.

**Is there an estimate on the number of names at this memorial from the video evidence?**

(And therefore the likely size of the region it covers?)

Comment: I saw _at least_ 7.

Answer (score 7):

In an early version of the script for *Avengers: Endgame*, it showed a lot of cities with their own Wall of the Vanished so that you really get the sense of the scale of the impact from the Snap. Barring any contradictory evidence, I think we can assume every city still has these and they just weren't shown so this one would just be for the city and possibly its surrounding area.

> **And that theme of loss is continued when Scott Lang visits a memorial to the dead in San Francisco.**
>
> **McFEELY** We used to have beats in the script where there are those in every city. Millions of names.
>
> **MARKUS** It’s that sense of collective trauma and the fact that if you weren’t killed, you wake up the next day — the trauma happened and I’m still here. How do we deal with this? That was the Stan Lee trick. Where’s the anxiety coming from? Now that they have Power X.
>
> <sub>[The New York Times, ‘Avengers: Endgame’: The Screenwriters Answer Every Question You Might Have](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/04/29/movies/avengers-endgame-questions-and-answers.html)</sub>

I don't think we really need to count the names on a stone, count the number of stones and estimate from there to come up with a rough figure. Instead we can use the rough population counts from our own world as there shouldn't be much of a difference. According to [World Population Review](http://worldpopulationreview.com/us-cities/san-francisco-population/) the population of San Francisco in 2018, when *Avengers: Infinity War* took place, was 883,305 and the population of San Francisco-Oakland-Hayward, CA Metro Area was 4,729,484. As the Snap took out *"half of all life"* we can figure it would take out roughly 50% of all life from San Francisco and its surrounding area. Therefore, there would be roughly between **441,652 and 2,364,742** names in the Wall of the Vanished.

Comment: Your wiggle room between 400k and 2M is exactly what I'm wondering about.   We don't have any idea whether this Wall is for the city of San Francisco, the entire Bay Area, all of Northern California, or what?

Comment: @ThePopMachine The above quote mentions "every city" so we can narrow it down to the city and its surrounding area. To be honest I'm not American and I don't really know what _"San Francisco-Oakland-Hayward, CA Metro Area"_ is referring to, to be able to get a narrower window.

Comment: While I can't dispute the accuracy of anything you put in your response, to be honest, this isn't answering the question.   The question is whether there's an estimate of the number of names depicted based on video evidence, not based on some reasoning about a comment from the screenwriters about something they didn't even put in the film.   That's not canon -- and it's not even very nailed down anyhow.

Comment: The population of the Bay Area is 7M.   So we could reasonably interpret this off-the-cuff comment by the screenwriters as only narrowing it down within a factor of almost 10!

Comment: @ThePopMachine It’s a reasonable answer to the question as asked just using a different more reasonable methodology. Their comment is probably either semi canon or full canon and not as low on the scale as you are are making out.

Comment: @thelethalcarrot the question as asked asks "Is there an estimate ... *from the video evidence*?" This does not answer that question.

Comment: @MattGutting If that was the entire question I'd agree with you (though even then still argue using an alternate method would be fine) but clearly the question is "how many names are there approximately". Using the video evidence is one methodology, using another way is also perfectly fine. What matters is the result.

Comment: I see where you're coming from, but considering that the sentence containing the quote I gave is bolded and given its own paragraph in the original, I think that should count as *the* question. (I have a couple of issues with the way you use math in the answer, but this is my main problem.)

Comment: @MattGutting Feel free to correct any maths mistakes in here, I'm no mathematician. As for the part about visual evidence I think we'll have to agree to disagree (note the title makes no mention of visual evidence).

Answer (score 4):

The [original concept art](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/marvelcinematicuniverse/images/5/58/Avengers_Endgame_Hargreaves_CA_24.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20190809142704) for the walls gives us an idea of their scope. Each wall appears to have approximately 4 names per line, 80 lines and double-sided, representing around 640(ish) names per stone. The park extends for some considerable distance, but we can see that each section contains roughly 9-12 stones (6400 names) and that there are at least [24 sections](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Wall_of_the_Vanished?file=Avengers_Endgame_Hargreaves_CA_22.jpg), representing a total of at least ***153,000* names.**

[image]

In [the film](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmpPb.png), there are 9 rows of 22 stones in the park visible. Assuming a similar *name density*, this is ***126,000* names**, approximately a third of those that vanished locally, given that the population of San Francisco city is over 800,000.

It's reasonable to assume that there are other similar-sized memorials in other parts of the city since Scott was able to walk to this park within a few minutes of his house.

Comment: Thank you -- I thought you'd have a go.

Comment: I guess my nitpick would be that you shouldn't base the estimate of the number of names per stone on concept art.   We can get this from the movie I'm sure.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - I've checked the closeups of the stones in the films and they're similar. I didn't think it sufficiently different as to require a separate calculation.